# AWS Appsync Graphql

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

With the recent changes to the Appsync Graphql transformer, I've been trying to migrate my code accordingly but seem to fail every time.

I'm following a straightforward tutorial on youtube that explains how to build a real-time chatting app.
The guy in the video develops his backend using the Appsync API with Graphql but is doing it with a V1 transformer.

I've tried to read the documentation and did change my code, but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.

**HIS CODE**

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  imageUri: String
  status: String
  chatRoomUser: [ChatRoomUser] @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
}

type ChatRoomUser
@model
@key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID", "chatRoomID"])
@key(name: "byChatRoom", fields: ["chatRoomID", "userID"]) {
  id: ID!
  userID: ID!
  chatRoomID: ID!
  user: User @connection(fields: ["userID"])
  chatRoom: ChatRoom @connection(fields: ["chatRoomID"])
}

type ChatRoom @model {
  id: ID!
  chatRoomUsers: [ChatRoomUser] @connection(keyName: "byChatRoom", fields: ["id"])
}
```

**MY CODE**

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  imageUri: String
  status: String
  chatRoomUser: [ChatRoomUser] @hasMany
}

type ChatRoomUser @model {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userID: ID! @index(name: "byUser", sortKeyFields: ["chatRoomID"])
  chatRoomID: ID! @index(name: "byChatRoom", sortKeyFields: ["userID"])
  user: User @belongsTo(fields: ["userID"])
  chatRoom: ChatRoom @belongsTo(fields: ["chatRoomID"]
}

type ChatRoom @model {
  id: ID!
  chatRoomUsers: [ChatRoomUser] @hasMany
}
```

These are his Query results with Aws

[image: His Query results look like this]

These are my Query results

[image: My Query results]

This is my auto-generated queries.js file

```
/* eslint-disable */
// this is an auto generated file. This will be overwritten

export const getUser = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetUser($id: ID!) {
    getUser(id: $id) {
      id
      name
      imageUri
      status
      chatRoomUser {
        items {
          id
          userID
          chatRoomID
          createdAt
          updatedAt
          userChatRoomUserId
          chatRoomChatRoomUsersId
        }
        nextToken
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
export const listUsers = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListUsers(
    $filter: ModelUserFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listUsers(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        name
        imageUri
        status
        chatRoomUser {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
export const getChatRoomUser = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetChatRoomUser($id: ID!) {
    getChatRoomUser(id: $id) {
      id
      userID
      chatRoomID
      user {
        id
        name
        imageUri
        status
        chatRoomUser {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      chatRoom {
        id
        chatRoomUsers {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
      userChatRoomUserId
      chatRoomChatRoomUsersId
    }
  }
`;
export const listChatRoomUsers = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListChatRoomUsers(
    $id: ID
    $filter: ModelChatRoomUserFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
    $sortDirection: ModelSortDirection
  ) {
    listChatRoomUsers(
      id: $id
      filter: $filter
      limit: $limit
      nextToken: $nextToken
      sortDirection: $sortDirection
    ) {
      items {
        id
        userID
        chatRoomID
        user {
          id
          name
          imageUri
          status
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        chatRoom {
          id
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        userChatRoomUserId
        chatRoomChatRoomUsersId
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
export const getChatRoom = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetChatRoom($id: ID!) {
    getChatRoom(id: $id) {
      id
      chatRoomUsers {
        items {
          id
          userID
          chatRoomID
          createdAt
          updatedAt
          userChatRoomUserId
          chatRoomChatRoomUsersId
        }
        nextToken
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
export const listChatRooms = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListChatRooms(
    $filter: ModelChatRoomFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listChatRooms(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        chatRoomUsers {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

This is his auto-generated queries.js files

```
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */
// this is an auto generated file. This will be overwritten

export const getUser = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetUser($id: ID!) {
    getUser(id: $id) {
      id
      name
      imageUri
      status
      chatRoomUser {
        items {
          id
          userID
          chatRoomID
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        nextToken
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
export const listUsers = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListUsers(
    $filter: ModelUserFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listUsers(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        name
        imageUri
        status
        chatRoomUser {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
export const getChatRoomUser = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetChatRoomUser($id: ID!) {
    getChatRoomUser(id: $id) {
      id
      userID
      chatRoomID
      user {
        id
        name
        imageUri
        status
        chatRoomUser {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      chatRoom {
        id
        chatRoomUsers {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
export const listChatRoomUsers = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListChatRoomUsers(
    $filter: ModelChatRoomUserFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listChatRoomUsers(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        userID
        chatRoomID
        user {
          id
          name
          imageUri
          status
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        chatRoom {
          id
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
export const getChatRoom = /* GraphQL */ `
  query GetChatRoom($id: ID!) {
    getChatRoom(id: $id) {
      id
      chatRoomUsers {
        items {
          id
          userID
          chatRoomID
          createdAt
          updatedAt
        }
        nextToken
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
export const listChatRooms = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListChatRooms(
    $filter: ModelChatRoomFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listChatRooms(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        chatRoomUsers {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

I would love it if someone could try and look at the code and tell me if there are any wrong pieces of code because after I run queries on the console, it doesn't give me the same results it provides to him.

I appreciate any help anyone can provide,
Matti

Comment: Can you add the query to your answer? How it's different from your expected query result?

Comment: Hi I've added what you asked for.

Comment: After *but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.*, could you please add (in two sentences) what you get and what you would expect? Reason: It's not immediately obvious what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using `primaryKey`(*which you are using userID and chatRoomID*) for `hasMany` relation. You need to add `indexName` in `User` and `ChatRoom` model's `@hasMany` directive.

`@belongsTo` and `@hasMany` indexName should be same for the that relation.

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  imageUri: String
  status: String
  chatRoomUser: [ChatRoomUser] @hasMany (indexName: "byUser")
}

type ChatRoomUser @model {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userID: ID! @index(name: "byUser", sortKeyFields: ["chatRoomID"])
  chatRoomID: ID! @index(name: "byChatRoom", sortKeyFields: ["userID"])
  user: User @belongsTo(fields: ["userID"])
  chatRoom: ChatRoom @belongsTo(fields: ["chatRoomID"]) 
}

type ChatRoom @model {
  id: ID!
  chatRoomUsers: [ChatRoomUser] @hasMany (indexName: "byChatRoom")
}
```

For more information, please check out the [Amplify GraphQL docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-many-relationship)